# Structuring models to return a list of objects

Tags: python, model-view-controller

I have a class that represents a Friend (model). This Friend has attributes and methods like any other model.

In order to show a webpage containing a list of all my friends I need to create a function to return that data.

My question: where should I put that function? Inside the Friend model (even though it will return a list of objects)? Or should I create some other model like FriendList that uses the Friend model?

Thank you

Comment: @Gab yeah, cause it's tagged as mvc

Comment: sure i saw, i was just wondering how you can suppose that it should be C# or vb.net... :p

Comment: actually I'm using python but the concept I'm trying to grasp is language agnostic

Comment: ok, I hope you're happy with my C# example then. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It depends on a great many things.**

About how big your project is, how your data is being structured, which pattern you would like to use, and much more.

Maybe you should have a look at these things first:

- [Design Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649977.aspx)
- [Domain Driven Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)

And based on the criterias on your software, you can determine what you need.

However, you could create a class called `Friends`, which extends your class `Friend`. Inside this class, you could have some loading functionality.

I would not put the Retrieving function in the Friend Class itself, mainly because it is not logical.

**Example Code**

```
class Friends : List<Friend>
{
public function bool RetrieveAll()
{
//load them here
}
}
```

**EDIT**: If you want to use MVC, you should go for Gab's answer, though.

Comment: :D
Nice links but, regarding the way the question is asked, i think it may be a bit complex for a first approach. MVP differ from MVC because the view is model agnostic. And this kind of approach should come later

Comment: You're right. I don't want to overwhelm him with links, that's why I also attached a simple example of how he could do it.
IMO reading these links is really enlightening and can help him in his decision making about what's best for his solution.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically your data will be stored in a resource external to the application. The Object in charge of retrieving those data is usually named DataAccessObject (DAO).

In your case you could have a FriendDAO which expose methode like

```
 List<Friend> retrieveAll();

 Friend retrieveByName(String name);

 persist(Friend friend);
```

etc...

The point of MVC is to clearly separate in different layers data persistence, manipulation and display.

You can have many variant, business logic may be located in model layer or in a controller, you can have a controller dedicated to view events handling (front controller) delegating to other controllers or to model.

The way you will name your classes is not so important.

Comment: :D and you would be right. Didn't wanted to tell that you can put anything as name but that they are many different way to name an object, although if sometimes some language specific or modeling terminology comes to top and becomes a reference, the only point is to be clearly understandable by everyone